# What package places thumbs into .local/share/previews

Tags: directory

I am interested, what package/software/tool places previews into `.local/share/previews`? I found just one preview in there, and am interested about where it came from.

Comment: Which version are you using? I have 12.04 and there is no 'previews' folder in `.local/share/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Unity Dash. If you right-click on a file in the Dash, a bigger preview is created, which is placed in this folder to speed up loading the next time.

You can test this by right-clicking an image or video file in the Dash and then see the newly created thumbnail in the folder.